# Howt to Retrive a latitude longitude of Multimarker in Android Google Maps V2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

i am making a sample App where a Multi markers are on Google Map on Button click i want to store all latitude longitude of each marker in Array List but one marker position is saved on per for loop length can any one tell me how to store a each marker latitude longitude pair in Array?

```
       for (int i=0; i<StopElement.Stop_name_list.size(); i++)
       {
            position = _Stop_marker.getPosition();
            GETLatLng = position.toString();
           _getlatlng = GETLatLng.substring(10, GETLatLng.length() - 1);

           get_coordinates.add(_getlatlng);
       }
```

Comment: What did you get on your code above? I think it ok.

Comment: i am retrieving a marker lat lng from one to another and saving it in Array list but its only saving one latlng @bjiang

Comment: What about others? There is something wrong with your `Stop_name_list`

Comment: I do this by storing all my markers in a HashMap with a key that allows me to pull out any marker. Or if you don't need a way to identify each marker, you could just store each marker in an ArrayList after adding to the map: mMap.addMarker(theMarker); myArrayList.put(theMarker); Then get the lat/lng with theMarker.getPosition().latitude and theMarker.getPosition().longitude